# How to draw multiple points on image

Tags: image, list, paint

When i am using code below to draw points over my image, each time i draw a new point, i am loosing my previous point, though i want to keep that as well.

```
void imageviewer :: paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{

    QLabel::paintEvent(e);

    if(mpaintflag)
    {
               QPainter painter(this);
               QPen paintpen(Qt::red);
               paintpen.setWidth(10);
               QPoint p1;
               p1.setX(mFirstX);
               p1.setY(mFirstY);
               painter.setPen(paintpen);
               painter.drawPoint(p1);
            }

}
```

I think that i can keep my previous points using QList, tried a lot, but still no idea how to do it using QList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it, i make a list (QList) to store the coordinate points, and then paint all the points in the list every time on image. That's how i did it.
Thanks